Dynamic require of 'https' is not supported error while generating cypress cucumber report in v 10
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "https"
node_modules/@ng-apimock/cypress-plugin/dist/cypress.plugin.js:4:22:
  4 │ const https = require("https");
    ╵                       ~~~~~~~

The package "https" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

cypress/support/e2e.js

I'm trying to generate a cypress cucumber report after migrating to cypress version 10 but cypress is throwing the above error and not able to run the tests

You can fix this error by upgrading to the latest version of @ng-apimock/cypress-plugin, version 3.0.0.
This current version no longer uses https module, see the code here
import { Configuration } from '@ng-apimock/base-client';
import urljoin = require('url-join');
import * as uuid from 'uuid';

import { RequestObject } from './request.object';

/** Cypress plugin for ng-apimock. */
export class CypressPlugin {
  ...

The diff of the change is here

Also make sure the package "@ng-apimock/core": "3.6.1" is installed, as obviously the Cypress plugin is depending on that library to work.
Then also check the following package versions:
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "15.1.1",
    "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "2.1.5",

